# Does し here mean the "do" verb stem or is it expressing reasons? And why is も used without は?

Tags: grammar

I'm reading [Tae Kim grammar](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/teform) and there is a sentence which I can't relate to either of two grammar rules (see topic name):

> Ａ：旅行の計画は終わった？
> A: Are the plans for the trip complete?
>
> Ｂ：うん、切符を買った**し**(!)、ホテルの予約**もし**(!)てある。
> B: Uh huh, not only did I buy the ticket, I also took care of the
> hotel reservations.

What do the **し** mean there? Also, why is there **も**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different し here. The first is the particle し, which can be used to list verbs/sentences in a way that is analogous to the way と
is used when listing nouns.

For example:

雨がふっているし、車がこしょうしているし、あかちゃんがないているし. . .
"It's raining, the car's broken down, the baby's crying . . ." There's no theoretical limit to the number of times you can use this particle in a list of sentences, but I'd say it usually comes in ones, twos or threes.

The second し, following 予約も, is simply the first syllable of して, the て form of する, in the pattern してある, "has been done".

ホテルの予約がしてある would mean "the hotel reservation has been made". Replace が with も and you have "the hotel reservation has been made, too", "the hotel reservation has been made as well".

So the whole means "Mm, I've bought the tickets, the hotel reservation has been made  . . . [and so on]". I'd say the use of し suggests that this is the first in a list of things, so there are other items that the speaker might have mentioned - "I've bought a new suitcase, I've cancelled the mail. . . "

Answer (score 4):

The first し is not from the verb する.  It means "and".  So the second sentence reads

> > Yes, I bought the tickets and the hotel also is reserved.

も is modifying 予約 providing the meaning of "also reserved".  The second し is actually して which is the て-form of the verb する.